# Adding multiple IDP for login

Tags: facebook, ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I followed this tutorial

> http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server/

and was able to redirect my application to wso2 login page and authenticate against a LDAP.

Now I want to add one more IDP, e.g. Facebook authentication, and allow users to login either through LDAP or Facebook after it is redirected to wso2 login page.

Is it possible, and if so can you refer me to any documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's possible.You can use any IDP (which support common protocols like SAML2, Auth2.0/openIdConnect) as a federated identity provider. WSO2 Identity server provide some outbound authenticators for popular Identity providers like facebook, google and twitter. You can use inbuilt Facebook authenticator to achieve this.

This is the official [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Logging+into+the+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials) for IS 5.0.0. 
Official [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Login+to+the+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials) for IS 5.1.0

Comment: Yes .This works fine when i want only facebook as my IDP.But what i am trying to achieve is ,once the user access my application i will redirect to wso2 for authentication,there user should be able to login either using FB login or LDAP credential. How can i display both options in the authenticate page

Comment: No. you can set both options in the log in page. then user can select any option. If user select facebook, then it will redirect to facebook login page

Comment: Go to `Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration -> Advanced Configuration` click Add Authentication Step when you create a service provider. and add both authenticators under Local Authenticators in the 1st step.If you add one for 1st step and another authenticator for second step, user has to login to authenticate from both authenticators. So better to add both authenticators in to 1st step.